# R Shiny server variable definition. modified value is not reflected

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Might be a basic question. But could not find a solution in the net.

Issue is i want to define a variable in `server.r` as below

```
function(input, output, session) {

  currentrunid <- ""
```

Then on a `submit` button click i want to assign a value to it.

```
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    currentrunid <- 1234  #Its dynamic
```

Then on a `status` button click i want to retrieve the value of the variable. The variable is used to retrieve the files generated as part of the submit.

```
observeEvent(input$checkstatus,{
   runid <- currentrunid
   Getoutputfiles(runid)
```

But the problem is the value assigned on submit Button is not available on Status button click.

Tried `session$currentrunid <- 1234` But got an error as below 
`cannot add bindings to a locked environment`

I have used `<<-` But i was suggested, i should not use this, instead, i should use `reactive` variable. But could not successfully implement it yet.

Please let me know what is the best practice here. Or how to implement `reactive`

Comment: What is your intention when you do `output$status <- currentrunid` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I create some output files as well as logfille with the currentrunid variable. And i use this variable to check if the files exist. In the example i have given just a small part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to do so I'm not sure this answer is appropriate. Maybe you need a reactive value, like this:

```
function(input, output, session) {

  currentrunid <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    currentrunid(1234) # this assigns 1234 
  })

  # to get the value, do currentrunid(), for example:
  observe({
    print(currentrunid())
  })

  ......
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for. Thanks